# c++ vectors - Using find(begin, end, term)

Tags: c++, vector, find

Ok, i'm doing this and it works fine.

```
end = std::find(arToken.begin() + nStart, arToken.end(), ".");
```

I want to extend the . to include ! and ? so it finds periods(.), exclamation mark(!), and question mark(?).

Should i use regex in the term?

TIA

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should use [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of):

```
std::string m(".!?");
end = std::find_first_of(arToken.begin() + nStart, arToken.end(), m.begin(),m.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/).  `std::find_first_of`

```
end=arToken.find_first_of(".!?",nStart);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be std::find_first_of?

Answer (score 2):

use a predicate and `std::find_if` like this:

```
struct has_char {
    has_char(const char *s) : str(s) {}
    bool operator() (const char ch) const {
        return str.find(ch) != std::string::npos;
    }
private:
    std::string str;
};

end = std::find_if(arToken.begin() + nStart, arToken.end(), has_char(".!?"));
```

Comment: Can you write that as if it was free function, so I could understand little easier. Thanks

Comment: since you're using std::string, you may want to stick with the methods that class provides.  I.e. in your operator() method, you can "return s.find(ch) != npos;"

Comment: also, to be strict about it, has_char should inherit from public std::unary_function<const char, bool>  -- which will require #include<functional>

Comment: @jerimiah: it can't be a free function cause it has state. Using a class with an overloaded `operator()` is the proper way to go if you use `find_if`

Comment: @Tim: it is usually a good idea to inherit from `std::unary_function<>`, but is only really required if you want to use binders and such. For the simple case of a predicate, you can usually get away with not doing that.